# Correct word order in sentences below

Tags: meaning

> A layer of gold with thickness of 200 nm which is produced by big mine company was coated onto table.

Gold layer has thickness of 200 nm and also it is Produced by very big mine company. I couldn't decided if word order is correct or not . Can this sentence be understood easily if the relative clauses is used after '' thickness of 200 nm.

> Doors of cabinet that are painted white will be repaired.

I think relative clauses modifes “doors” in this sentence . But it is away from the “doors”.

> A frame in the shape of circle hanged on the wall suddenly broke.

And I think what is hanged on the wall is frame not circle. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of multiple modifiers is a difficult issue of style. In general, your sentences will be clearer and more idiomatic if you keep modifiers as close as possible to the word modified. This often leads to substantial rewording.

For your first sentence, it would be far better to say

> The table was layered, 200 nm. thick, in gold from a very big mining company.

or

> Gold from a very big mining company was layered, 200 nm. thick, on the table.

One wonders whether the description of who produced the gold is even relevant.

Your second sentence if strictly construed does modify "doors, but might be misunderstood. It does mean

> Cabinets with white painted doors will be repaired

but no one will be surprised if it is interpreted as

> White painted cabinets with doors will be repaired.

Notice that all ambiguity can be removed by using adjectives that immediately precede the noun being modified.

Your third sentence will indeed be understood as meaning that the frame hung on the wall broke because a circle is an ideal concept that can neither break nor be hung on a wall. It is a type of construction commonly heard in speech. In formal writing, I'd recommend as more immediately comprehensible

> The circular frame that was hung on the wall broke.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood you very well. And I always try to make sentence in the way you advised me. But I wonder if my sentences above can be understood if the one I spoke to ,knew what I was talking about .

Comment: In speech and informal writing, people are often far from exact in expressing meaning, Consequently, native English speakers are good at extracting intended meaning from unclear expressions, particularly when overall context is understood. In dialogue, moreover, there is opportunity to identify and eliminate potential misunderstanding. So, yes, you can speak like this with little risk of being misunderstood. The big problem comes in email and other informal writing, where tone of voice, facial expression, etc. do not supplement the actual words.